# Safari, css width: 100% does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

In the safari (I'm testing on IOS 9) the width is not 100%.

We will say 4 columns of them 1 and the last 2 are fake in size, 50 by 50 px. And the second is where the logo (for example, chose any), he must beat the width of 100%. In other browsers, everything works fine, except for safari the left edge of the 2 column crawls on 1. I painted the squares so that it was visible and the logo put the height less than the special. so that it was visible.

```css
.custom {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.mobicon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  background: #65b7ff;
}

.custom div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.search-toggle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #1b1b01;
  background: antiquewhite;
}

.header_logo {
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* height: 100%; */
  height: 45px;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: aqua;
}

#jshop_module_cart div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom">
  <div class="uk-visible-small">
    <div class="mobicon uk-navbar-toggle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-visible-small">
    <div class="header_logo">
      <a href="/"><img src="https://staticaltmetric.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2015/10/dark-logo-for-site.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-visible-small">
    <div class="search-toggle"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div id="jshop_module_cart">
    <div class="mobcart">


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nos1j6n/4/)**